# Problems when adding key-value pair to plist file in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a view controller in an iphone app that adds a key-value pair to a plist file. It then displays the entire plist in a view controller with a table view. The problems I'm having are that it will only display the values in the iPhone simulator and it will only display the new key-value pairs if I completely restart the app.

NOTE: The plist file is supposed to be added to the app's resources directory
UPDATE: the code below is the solution to my question, additionally, to view the new entries in the plist, I implemented a refresh button that basically ran the section in viewDidLoad.

The code for the view controller that adds the key-value pair is below:

```
- (IBAction)addAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{    
    NSString *myFile=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"plist"];

    dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myFile];

    NSArray *docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath=[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];

    //Check plist's existance using FileManager
    NSError *err=nil;
    NSFileManager *fManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if(![fManager fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
    {
        //file doesn't exist, copy file from bundle to documents directory

        NSString *bundlePath=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"File" ofType:@"plist"];
        [fManager copyItemAtPath:bundlePath toPath:plistPath error:&err];
    }

    //Get the dictionary from the plist's path
    dictionary =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
    //Manipulate the dictionary
    [dictionary setObject:textContent forKey:textName];
    //Again save in doc directory.
    [dictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];    
}
```

This is the code to display the plist in a table view in the other view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Initialize table data

    NSArray *docDir=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath=[docDir objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *plistPath=[filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"File.plist"];


    dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:**plistPath**];
    verses = [dictionary allKeys];

    [self.mainTableView reloadData];

}
```

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Are you calling -(void)reloadData on the UITableView after you've added to the plist? Assuming the tableview is using the plist as its data source.

Comment: I wasn't at first but I just tried it now, and it's still doing the same behaviour as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On device the main bundle is read only you want to write to the documents directory path. You can get it via

NSArray paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

The reason why your changes are only appearing on launch is because the file names don't match

Comment: I see.. but I'm already doing that in the view controller that writes the new key-value pair. Do you mean to put that in the view controller that displays it?

Comment: @user1186173 you appear to (1) load the plist from your bundle; (2) make a copy of the file into your documents folder; (3) save a new copy of the plist into your bundle. On iOS the bundle is read only so the net effect will be that you have the original unmodified file still in the bundle because you failed to modify it and a copy of the original unmodified file in your documents directory because you didn't even attempt to modify it. Check especially your call to `writeToFile:`. And, yes, if you want to read back values from your documents copy later you'll need to open the documents copy.

Comment: OHH you're right. That makes sense, I was adding it to the original file path which isn't the right one at all... Sorry for not catching that, I'm still very new to this. So I changed a couple things (see the original code where there are **) and I can now see the first line I added, but if I add anymore I'll have to restart the app to see it. I'm assuming I'm doing something wrong where I view it.

Comment: So what I had to do was add a button and an action that would basically redo the initial viewDidLoad process. I would prefer to have it load automatically all the time but this will do for now. Thank you very much for you help